# Search controller logic to search through models and manufacturers

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I have the following Laravel controller that searches through two models - Manufacturer and SearchTerm (which contains models of manufacturers, synonyms of models as well as common misspellings) using four different conditions: the first two for exact matches and the last two for partial matches.

I don't have a lot of experience with programming logic like this, and while it does thankfully work, it also seems to run very slow on my local server (2-3 seconds returning results from tables that are currently less than a hundred rows).

#### Controller

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Manufacturer $manufacturer) {
        if (request("search")) {

        $exact_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', request("search"))->get();
        if($exact_terms->isNotEmpty()) {
            echo "Exact search term match!";
            $results = $exact_terms;

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $slug = $result->manufacturer->slug;
            }

            return redirect()->action([ManufacturerController::class, 'index'], ["manufacturer" => $slug]); 
        }

        $exact_make = Manufacturer::where('slug', request("search"))->get();
        if($exact_make->isNotEmpty()) {
            echo "Exact manufacturer match!";
            $results = $exact_make;

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $slug = $result->slug;
            }
            
            return redirect()->action([ManufacturerController::class, 'index'], ["manufacturer" => $slug]); 
        }

        $search_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', "like", '%' . request("search") . '%')->get()->unique("manufacturers");
        if($search_terms->isNotEmpty()) {
            echo "Search term match!";
            foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) {
                $search_term = $search_term->manufacturer;
            }
            $results = collect()->add($search_term); // Needed to always return a collection to the view, even if made up of one object
        } 

        $search_make = Manufacturer::where('slug', 'like', '%' . request("search") . '%')->get();
        if($search_make->isNotEmpty()) {
            echo "Manufacturer match!";
            $results = $search_make;
        }

    $results = isset($results) ? $results : collect();
    }
    
    return view("search", [
    "manufacturer" => $manufacturer,
    "results" => $results,
]);
}
}
```

#### View

```
@if(!$results->isEmpty())

<h1 class="my-5"> {{ $results->count() }} {{ $results->count() == 1 ? "result" : "results" }} found for <i>{{ request("search") }}</i></h1>

@foreach ($results as $result)
<img src="{{ asset("/images/badges/".$result->slug.".svg")}}" class="search-result-badge" alt="...">
<h2>{{$result->name}}</h2>

@endforeach    
@else
<p><h1>Sorry! We couldn't find any results for <i>"{{ request("search") }}"</i>.</h1></p>
<br>
@endif
```

Comment: Maybe you can also inspect these [two](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) [packages](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-searchable) and see what they did there.

Comment: This looks questionable: `foreach ($results as $result) { $slug = $result->manufacturer->slug; }` ...is the intention to keep overwriting the `$slug` variable in a loop and only preserve the final value?  This technique is repeated two more times in your code.  Please explain.  And `$results` keeps getting overwritten.  Lots of red flags on this question to be honest.  I'm leaning toward "Not Working As Intended".

Comment: @mickmackusa The code is for searching and it does that, so I think the question is on-topic, based on meta which says in order to be off topic code has to be ["very obviously broken (won't run at all, or fails on a simple test case)"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/104611).

Comment: @Laurel I don't use laravel, so don't know if it is broken.  I was just seeing several red flags. I don't know if those queries might return multiple results -- if so, it is not working as intended. If you say it is not broken, okay.

Comment: @mickmackusa The solution definitely works but as I said I don't have much experience with programming logically so I don't know how well it works for edgecases. No, that wasn't the intention, it was just the best way I could figure out at the time of getting the relevant slug into a variable while also making sure what was being returned to the view was still a Collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Controller

#### For loops with discarded $results

This is weird:

```php
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $slug = $result->slug; // or similar
}
```

You go through all that effort to get potentially a lot of matches, and then only use the last result. Why? If you only want one result, then you shouldn't `get()` a bunch of results. Only get the `first()`, perhaps after sorting appropriately. For example:

```
// First one:
$exact_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', request("search"))->first();

// Highest ID:
$exact_terms = SearchTerm::with("manufacturer")->where('term', request("search"))->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

I expect this is where the performance problem is.

#### Echos

What is the point of `echo` here? The only time that you would see it was while testing, so it should be removed after you've finished debugging those sections.

#### Sanitizing user input

The user can mess around with your `like` searches by entering a lot of `%`s in `request("search")` which may affect performance a little. I would strip these out, in addition to backslash and underscore.

(To clarify, you will need to keep the percents you are concatenating around `request("search")` as this is the only way to perform the query you want.)

#### Invert if

Your code has a bug, and this shows it. Where does `$results` come from when `request("search")` is missing? (Remember, frontend validation can be bypassed.)

```
if (!request("search")) {
    return view("search", ["manufacturer" => $manufacturer, "results" => $results, ]);
}
// Otherwise...
```

You'll have to have a return at the bottom but that's a small price to pay for not having so much indenting

#### Make the collection in a more readable way

`collect()->add($search_term);` becomes `collect([$search_term]);`, which is the same but more readable.

#### Null coalesce

`$results = isset($results) ? $results : collect();` becomes `$results ??= collect();`. If you're not using PHP 7.4 to be able to do this, then update!

#### Return earlier with `$search_terms`

You throw away the results from a match with `$search_terms` when you have a match for $search_make. Not doing that would also allow you to streamline that part of the code.

### View

#### Use whitespace for readability

Indent properly! The same goes for the controller.

Use spaces inside braces: `{{ $content }}`, not `{{$content}}`. Also use spaces around concatenation: `$str . $str`, not `$str.$str`.

#### Alt text

Don't use "..." as an alt text because that doesn't help a screen reader to know what's there. It seems appropriate here to leave it blank (to tell the screen reader to skip the image) as the image doesn't add anything to a screen reader beyond what they already can understand with `$result->name` on the next line.

#### Pluralization

In Laravel 9 you can use the helper `str()->plural()` (with the new, shorter syntax that makes it worth using in Blade). If you plan to localize, then you'll need to use [`trans_choice`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#pluralization) instead.

#### Invalid HTML

It's not valid to have a `h1` inside a `p`.

#### Invert if

Specifically, `!$results->isEmpty()` can become `$results->isNotEmpty()` which is probably more readable.

#### My rewrite of your view

```
@if($results->isNotEmpty())
    <h1 class="my-5"> {{ $results->count() . ' ' . str('result')->plural($results->count()) }} found for <i>{{ request("search") }}</i></h1>
    @foreach ($results as $result)
        <img src="{{ asset("/images/badges/" . $result->slug . ".svg")}}" class="search-result-badge" alt="">
        <h2>{{ $result->name }}</h2>
    @endforeach
@else
    <h1>Sorry! We couldn't find any results for <i>"{{ request("search") }}"</i>.</h1>
    <br>
@endif
```

PS I'm not sure if `asset("/images/badges/" . $result->slug . ".svg"` is vulnerable to directory traversal. I hope your slug is not user-generated, or is otherwise heavily sanitized.

Comment: Some great tips here and much less radical than I thought it would be - I assumed that my general approach of using `if` loops would be bad. RE: the `for` loops - the first two are to isolate the slug into a variable for the purpose of the `return view()`, and the third one was to make every searchterm return a manufacturer, which would allow me to just do `$result->slug` on the view for all of the search results. Essentially to prevent as much conditional checking in the view as possible, in hindsight maybe laziness/optimising the wrong side.

Comment: Similarly with `collect()->add($search_term)` - it's to force the search result (which is often an object of one, but not always) into a Collection. By doing this the search conditions always return Collections that can then easily be output in Blade without additional logic. Maybe I went about this the wrong way and it's worth making the Blade file a little less clean for the sake of returning only the results I need. Although it's worth nothing that only two of the conditions *always* return just one result so for the other two a `get()` will always be needed.

Comment: Interestingly I was under the impression that is required when using `LIKE` in SQL. If not, what does it add and why is it so commonly used? Also regarding the loading of images, all the slugs are generated by me, but is this a typical way to load images/assets? It seems there should be a more idiomatic Laravel way of doing this that doesn't hardcode paths, but maybe this is the more common way to do it.

Comment: I now see what you're saying about `collect()` and have implemented accordingly. However, my SQL queries simply don't work without wrapping them in `%`.

Comment: @HashimAziz I also clarified that part about percents. If you want to see what the problem is with it, have the user search for something like `b%t`, which would match "boot" and "boat". Similarly, if they searched for `_` that would match everything.

Comment: Ah, so basically the SQL wildcard. How would this stripping be done? I did a quick search but it didn't seem to bring up anything relevant.

Comment: Also what do you think about [the approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/98887/117831) of using `match` instead of `like`? Is it possible/worth implementing in my case?

Comment: @HashimAziz You can use str_replace in PHP to remove characters from a string. The MATCH solution looks fine (as long as you make sure to format it like that, in a way that prevents SQL injection), but I really wonder if implementing the first section of my answer would solve most of your performance problems without it. I have a search function in my website where a user can search "john bob" and it matches with LIKE across first and last name columns (returning "**John**athan **Bob**" and "Ro**bob**erty O'**John**son") and it doesn't have any performance issues w/ 500+ people in the db.